# How can I effectively build Wynne as a healer?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I've been going around on the internet and the builds they give for Healer Wynne are not really preferable.

I wanted to build Wynne that would focus more on healing and providing buffs for the team. If it's possible to expand her sets I'd like to add spells like Mana Clash. What should I be adding to her set? How do I arrange the tactics for it? What about the stats?

Answer (score 4):

I set Wynne to:

```
Ally -> HP < 50% -> Heal

Ally -> HP < 25% -> Lifeward

Ally -> HP < 0% -> Revival
```

You can also set up Group Heal if your team bunches up when the fight. I pretty much auto-cast Group Heal though because it's really good when you can do it yourself in most situations.

The stats should mostly be Magic and Willpower. I usually go 2 Magic and 1 Willpower when I build her, sometimes throwing some stats into Constitution here and there for survivability.

Comment: Thanks! That really made the stats look better and she seems to work better now. Although, I still need help on the skills I need to get and tactics on those skill. I was thinking if I'm getting Cleanse Aura then I wouldn't need to get anything from the Heal tree. Thanks for your help though!